# Проблема с Wordpress. Блок админ.панели. Что делать?

Tags: wordpress

Как не вводил бы данные - вход блокирует. Возникла проблема после перемены главной (стат) страницы с украинской версии на английскую. wp-admin и wp-login.php бесполезны - ничего не работает. Проблема не в бэкапе и пароле. И вряд-ли в секьюрити-плагине.

Comment: Расписать подробнее, что случилось. Смена главной страницы на админку не влияет

Comment: Заказчик решил поменять статическую страницу с версии с Украинским языком на Английский, там была разная структура по шрифтам, цветам, изображениям. Сразу же после этого ikp.com.ua приобрела вид, который вы сейчас можете увидеть. Решение проблемы может быть в смене страницы  в исходный вид (т.е на укр), но я не имею понятия как это сделать на isp manager. Спасибо!